# How to remove white space after sequence of characters in a csv file?

Tags: regex, csv, whitespace

Can anybody point me to where i can write a script to remove white space in a csv file, however i only want to remove white space after a specific sequence of character(s) so i expect to need Regular Expressions

```
fName, lName, age, address 1 address 2, <example>   <tag>  </tag>  </example>
fName, lName, age, address 1 address 2, <example>   <tag>  </tag>  </example>
fName, lName, age, address 1 address 2, <example>   <tag>  </tag>  </example>



EDIT:
Desired outcome: 

fName, lName, age, address 1 address 2, <example><tag></tag></example>
fName, lName, age, address 1 address 2, <example><tag></tag></example>
fName, lName, age, address 1 address 2, <example><tag></tag></example>
```

So in the example above, i would like to remove the white space before and after the brackets in the tags, but leave the space in the other values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This kind of depends on what you're using to make these changes... Perl? PHP? Python? Sed?  AWK?  Also, you should show us what you'd like the desired output to be, so there's no confusion.

Answer (score 2):

In perl:

```
s/\s+</</g;
s/>\s+/>/g;
```

Will remove leading spaces before `<` and trailing spaces after `>`.

Also, based on your update; if you just want to remove whitespace between `>` and `<` you can simply do `s/>\s+</></g;`

Comment: You could do pretty much the exact same command with `sed -i` to edit existing files.